# Menu to overlay rather than slide content

Tags: jquery, overlay, slidetoggle

I'm trying to implement a simple mobile menu which overlays the content rather than Slides the below content down.

I've been using slideToogle and thought a simple Show would do the trick but it's not the case.

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=CeCLTjgp1G

Comment: your fiddle is not working

Comment: Sorry I thought I made it Public (by giving it a Title) but it hasn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery to add class:

```
 $('#responsive-menu-button').click(function () {
    $('.nav').addClass("show");
});
```

Class:

```
nav {
    display:none;
}
nav.show {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    background:#F7F7F7;
}
```